# "Please point out the vue-storefront to image proxy provided"

Tags: vue-storefront

In the installation instructions: https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/windows.html#installation-of-vue-storefront

Step 6 of frontend says this:

> Images: because vue-storefront-api uses imagemagick and some nodejs command line bindings it can be difficult to run the image proxy on localhost/windows machine. Please point out the vue-storefront to image proxy provided by changing config/local.json images.baseUrl:

I am struggling to understand what `Please point out the vue-storefront to image proxy provided` means.

What is the image proxy provided?  Where do I get the value to point to?

Answer (score 0):

The `baseUrl: 'https://demo.vuestorefront.io/img/'` is a proxy because it doesn't STORE the images directly, but rather fetches the URL from provided param then converts the image and returns converted source.

You can provide normal vue-storefront-api `/img` endpoint, BUT you can also implement your own converted-image-provider (called proxy here) same way as described on:
https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-integration-sdk/blob/tutorial/Dynamic%20API%20specification.md#img

normally, you simply point it to:
`https://your-vue-storefront-api.domain.com/img/`

the reason this doc has it pointed to the same domain as vue-storefront URL is described in 
https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/installation/production-setup.html#nginx
(where they redirect `/img` requests to port :8080 on the same host) so in their example vue-storefront is running on the same host as vue-storefront-api)